# Unity changes the guid of all meta files when i clone my repository from github

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, repository

every time I clone my repository onto my other computer unity automatically changes the GUID how do I stop this?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you commit the .meta files and are they modified after a first import, or are you saying that .meta files appear in your git status after a clone and import?

Comment: When I open up github.com the correct meta files are there but as soon as the project is opened up in unity it changes all the meta files GUID's

Comment: That is really strange then. If it is a fully fresh clone (which succeeds), that should not happen. Grasping at straws here, but once you do a fresh clone, and then open the project, are there any error messages in the console? Before you open the project for the first time, do the .meta files seem to be correct once cloned?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was trying to make a tool that would help make unity games but I made the mistake of making it put the brand new unity game that my code generated inside my assets folder this caused all the meta files to conflict